# My computer wont shutdown

Tags: shutdown

If I try to shutdown my computer it simply takes me back to the login-screen.
I looked around and found :

Type in terminal:

1. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Find the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
3. Change this to:`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`
4. Save the file and close the file.
5. Finally, in terminal: `sudo update-grub`

But now there is a new problem when I try step 5 it says:

```
*myname*@ubuntu:~$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for *myname*: 
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).
*myname*@ubuntu:~$
```

I am new whit linux and dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to shut it down from the Terminal?

```
sudo shutdown -P 1
```

*(Also, try to use some Formatting when Posting here, so your Question is more Readable **;-)***

Comment: yes that works thanks,
The system shutdown normally now...

Comment: I am glad I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the Grub worked for me great.

`sudo shutdown` only reset my system until I adjusted the Grub and then it worked great.

I did the above steps you have done then I removed `acpi=force` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and added it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` instead, (i.e. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=force"`).

Then I shut down the computer, using the power button to power off after it stopped shutting down at the black screen with a series of messages that ended with "[end trance ...]" as it did before (I had `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` to show messages instead of the splash screen). After re-booting, shutdown worked correctly.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)