# Ubuntu 13.04 shutdown problem. Got no idea what to do next

Tags: shutdown

I have been using Ubuntu for two years now and had few actual problems. I have searched this site and tried various things to no effect. I will do my best to explain, and certainly include too much info as I have no idea what my problem really is. Please take answers to the 'for dummies'-level and I shall certainly do my best to understand!

So, I have this lovely acer TravelMate 5310 from around 07 that's causing a bit of a headache. It's Vista was removed and replaced with Ubuntu 11.?? some two years ago and was updated to the 12.04 LTS at some point before christmas. It has worked well except a problem with the network that's solved with a plug in reciever. All was just fine until I two days ago wanted to install the latest version, 13.04. I by accident installed 12.04LTS again and thought it won't matter. The problem with shutdown started after this, and we have finally arrived at the point of all this.

It won't shut down. I removed the 12 and installed the 13 last night thinking the problem might go away. It installed and updated and whent for a restart without problems but came to a halt at the purple screen.

I performed the hard shutdown(the press button method) and restarted. It boots up with ease and all is really well BUT it simply cannot shut down. It now hangs on a black screen with loads of white numbers, words and other such terminal-like things. So I push and hold shutdown to turn it off.

I tried the answer from [my computer won't shut down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201107/my-computer-wont-shutdown/%22this%22). 
Then tried the `acpi=off` in terminal but nothing works. I have yet to try the command `shutdown -h now` but I now managed to hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> at the right time and go behind the first screen and see the next. I am sorry that I have no pictures to show you.

The processes that seems to fail are two:

```
*killing all remaining processes....                              [fail]  
modem-manager[953] : <info> Caught signal 15, shutting down...
```

then follows `ok's` on deactivating swaps, unmounting filesystems.
then:

```
*stopping remanining crypto discs...       [ok]  
*stopping early crypto discs...            [fail]  
Unmount:  /run/lock:  not mounted  
unmount:  /run/shm:  not mounted  
mount: / is busy  
  *will now halt
```

And that is where it hangs..
I hope you are able to understand anything. I have no idea.

Comment: Why does the title have 13.10 and the body have 13.04?

Comment: Check if doing `sudo poweroff` on a terminal helps. This is not a permanent solution, just a workaround, if it works!

Comment: I don't know about `poweroff`, but I do `shutdown -h now` when I need to "force" a shutdown and works just fine.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 13.10 you should report it as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the instructions from [Shutdown does not power off computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer)

Type in terminal:

1. `sudo -i`  (to get a root shell, sudo gedit is not recommended)
2. `gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. Find the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
4. Change this to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`
5. Save the file and close the file.
6. Finally, in terminal: `update-grub`
7. `exit`  (to end the root shell)

Comment: This did not worked for me.